# Support questions that involve Third-Party components

Tags: discussion, support

**Are support questions that involve Third-Party components allowed?**

I just deleted a post, thinking I should ask this question first, in which I asked something like:

AutoPager (Chrome) plugin not showing Subscribed Tag highlight on any page past the first...

Screenshot
[image]

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 and have tested with the latest Chrome and Chromium.

It does, however, work on Firefox 3.6.24

I plan on contacting the AutoPager developer and Tim Banks who created the AutoPager Rule for stackoverflow.com

**Would a question like this be acceptable on meta?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it's about software use, not software programming, I'd say they don't belong on SO period.  As Robert Harvey points out, "if it's a bug or feature request for Stack Overflow proper, it belongs here," meaning on Meta [it appears he interpreted this as asking whether it belongs on Meta, and I interpreted it as SO].  If you phrase it as asking for a workaround, it may be on-topic on another site, perhaps Superuser.  Otherwise, it probably doesn't belong on the SE network at all.

Comment: Understandable. I will go ahead and contact the author. And, I did mean here on Meta.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a bug or feature request for Stack Overflow proper, it belongs here, regardless of whether or not a third-party component is involved.

If you want support for a third-party component that Stack Overflow happens to use, you might be better off contacting the author of the third-party component.